# PyTorch broadcast multiplication of 4D and 2D matrix?

Tags: python, pytorch, broadcast, torch

How do I broadcast to multiply these two matrices together?

```
x: torch.Size([10, 120, 180, 30]) # (N, H, W, C)
W: torch.Size([64, 30]) # (Y, C)
```

The output should be:

```
(10, 120, 180, 64) == (N, H, W, Y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `x` is some kind of example with batches and `w` matrix is the corresponding weight. In this case you could simply do:

```
out = x @ w.T
```

which is a **tensor multiplication**, not an element-wise one. You can't do element-wise multiplication to get such shape and this operation would not make sense. All you could do is to `unsqueeze` both of the matrics in some way to have their shape broadcastable and apply some operation over dimension you don't want for some reason like this:

```
x : torch.Size([10, 120, 180, 30, 1])
W: torch.Size([1, 1, 1, 30, 64]) # transposition would be needed as well
```

After such `unsqueezing` you could do `x*w` and `sum` or `mean` along the third `dim` to get desired shape.

For clarity, both ways **are not** equivalent.